# t-sql join query with weird condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have three members that belong to the company and the third member is an admin

Given number three user id (03) I need to get all other members who belong to the same company who are not admin

Please help

Comment: oh... not admin.  so `<>'02'` or `<>'Admin'` and then where `user.id<>'03'` or `links.user<>'03'... just... select * from link where group<>'02' and user<>'03' and join in user and group tables if you want that extra data (names n such), too.

Comment: third member is not admin... btw.  and there are four users.

Comment: why on earth do your IDs have leading zeros? please tell me they are not strings!

Comment: @KM just for illustration

Answer (score 0):

edited after commentary. inner select no longer returns admin group. using `in` instead of `=`.

i suggest an approach where you define the admin users and then select all the users from the same group as the given user id and then exclude the first list. like this:

```
declare @searchuser varchar(2) = '03';

with admins as (
    select [user]
      from [Link] l
      join [Groups] g
        on l.[Group] = g.[id]
     where g.[name] != 'Admin'
)
select u.[id]
     , u.[name]
  from [Users] u
  join [Link] l
    on u.[id] = l.[user]
 where l.[Group] in (select [Group] 
                       from [Link] 
                      where [user] = @searchuser 
                        and [Group] != (select [id] 
                                          from [Groups] 
                                         where [name] != 'Admin')
                    )
   and u.[id] not in (select [user] from admins)
   and u.[id] != @searchuser
```

Comment: Same problem as Gordon's answer, the subquery returns more than 1 value and you are using an =.

Comment: the admin user belongs to "company" and "Admin" group, so select [Group] from [Link] where [user] = @searchuser will not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select l.user
from link l join
     groups g
     on l.group = g.id
where l.group = (select g3.group
                 from link l3 join
                      groups g3
                      on l3.group = g.id and g.name = 'Company'
                 where l3.user = '03'
                ) and
      g.name <> 'Admin';
```

Note that `group` is a reserved word in SQL Server (as well as all other databases).  You shouldn't use reserved words for column or table names.  I assume the example uses simplified names.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value: this code doesn't work because you need to use an IN and not = when checking the company, user 3 is in both.

Comment: @KevinCook  . . . Now I realize I'm totally confused.  What does it mean to be in the same company?

Comment: The example the user gave was bad, he should have made at least 2 access levels for different companies rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some test data

```
DECLARE @users TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @users
VALUES
( 1, 'one' ),
( 2, 'two' ),
( 3, 'three' ),
( 4, 'four' ),
( 5, 'five' );

DECLARE @groups TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @groups
VALUES
( 1, 'CompanyA' ),
( 2, 'CompanyB' ),
( 3, 'CompanyC' ),
( 4, 'CompanyD' ),
( 5, 'AdminA' ),
( 6, 'AdminB' ),
( 7, 'AdminC' ),
( 8, 'AdminD' ),
( 9, 'AdminAll' );

DECLARE @link TABLE
(   
    USERID int,
    GROUPID int
)

INSERT INTO @link
VALUES
( 1, 1 ),
( 2, 1 ),
( 3, 1 ),
( 3, 2 ),
( 3, 5 ),
( 4, 2 ),
( 5, 1 ),
( 5, 2 ),
( 5, 9 );
```

Now we just check to see who has company access, but does not have company admin access (or admin over all company access)

```
SELECT * 
FROM @users u
INNER JOIN @link l
ON l.USERID = u.ID
INNER JOIN @groups g
ON g.ID = l.GROUPID
WHERE u.ID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT l.USERID 
    FROM @link l
    INNER JOIN @groups g
        ON g.ID = l.GROUPID
    WHERE g.NAME = 'AdminB' OR g.NAME = 'AdminAll'
)
AND g.NAME = 'CompanyB'
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    USERID  GROUPID ID  NAME
3   three   3   2   2   CompanyB
4   four    4   2   2   CompanyB
```

Comment: what is there are more than one company?

Comment: then you would add a where clause for the company desired, your test case only had company and admin.

Comment: I have added a more complex example with multiple admin types and multiple companies

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't use a subquery

```
select A.* from user A join Link B on A.id = B.[User] 
join Groups C on B.Group = C.id and c.id <> '02'
join (select A.id, B.Group from user A join link B on A.id = B.user where id = '03') D on
B.Group = D.Group
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you only need users who belong to the same company who are not Admin, here is what I did: First Created all the tables as you have, then inserted the data, and ran the query to get the desired results:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[groups]
    (
        [id] [int] NULL,
        [name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) 


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users]
    (
        [ID] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Link]
    (
        [user] [int] NULL,
        [group] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) 

;WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT U.ID, U.NAME, L.[group]
FROM users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Link] L ON U.ID = L.[user]

)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE [group] <> 2 AND cte.ID NOT IN (  SELECT [user]
                                        FROM Link
                                        WHERE [group] = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
 except
```

get the list of users from ling who belongs to "Company"

except

get the list of users who belong to  "Admin"

Comment: then why flag this as only tsql and not c#/linq?